# Passing values between pages using javascript

Tags: javascript

I know we can store values in `window` object.

```
var obj = {
   name: 'John', company: 'XYZ', salary: '$x'
};

window.getValue = obj;
```

But using `window` object is not recommended since it will cause overhead on the browser. Is there another way to pass values between pages in Javascript?

We can use the global variables (declared outside function scope)

```
var x = {
    product: 'phone', price: '$x';
};

(function(){
    // module code
})();
```

Is there another way apart from using global variables or `window` object?

Comment: What do you mean by "between pages"? Any properties added to the `window` object will not be persisted between page-loads (unless you're communicating across iframes?). If you want to persist data then use the `localStorage` API.

Comment: using iframes? yes, but both pages should be in the same domain

Comment: Also see this: https://github.com/colorhook/crossdomain